# What is "which" referring to in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning, grammar, expressions, complex-sentences

In the following sentence, I'm confused about what "through **which**" refers to.

> Following these transformations, companies brought market mechanisms
> into their internal functioning on a massive scale, as attested by
> waves of outsourcing, the dismantling of conglomerates, efforts to
> refocus on their core business, the hiring of temporary workers, and
> the emergence of global value chains, **through which** a myriad of
> independent firms contribute to the production of a single product.

Considering the textual meaning, I presume **which** refers to *the emergence of global value chains*, but I'm not sure why comma is used between "global value chains" and "a myriad of independent firms contribute to the production of a single product".

That makes me confused whether "which" refers to the word right before "through which" or "which" refers to the whole sentence that came before "through which".

Could you give some tips on this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That "which" refers to the whole of "waves of outsourcing, the dismantling of conglomerates, efforts to refocus on their core business, the hiring of temporary workers, and the emergence of global value chains." The result of all that outsourcing etc was many independent firms contributing towards the product.

Comment: It could refer to the entire phrase, as suggested in the earlier comment, or it could refer only to *global supply chains*. Syntactically, it's more common for it to be referring only to the single thing—which is how I intuitively *want* to interpret it. But semantically, when looking at the entire sentence, it probably makes more sense for it to be referring to everything. I suspect the author meant it to refer to everything, but it's ambiguous. The sentence really needs to be rewritten in order to simplify it and make the meaning clearer.